# Salesforce report & group

Tags: reporting

**I have some fields in my Opportunity object:**

> - YEAR1 (text field)
> - YEAR2 (text field)
> - YEAR3 (text field)
> - NUMBER1 (number field)
> - NUMBER2 (number field)
> - NUMBER3 (number field)
> - BOOL1 (Check box)
> - BOOL2 (Check box)
> - BOOL3 (Check box)

**Here's an example of dates:**

> OPPORTUNITY 1 :
>
> - 2012
> - 2013
> - 2014
> - 1
> - 2
> - 3
> - YES
> - YES
> - NO

**OPPORTUNITY 2:**

> - 2014
>
>   - 2013
>   - 2012
>   - 4
>   - 5
>   - 6
>   - NO
>   - NO
>   - YES

**Here's the algorithm of my wanted report:**

> - O1.BOOL1 ? YES, so 2012 += 1
> - O1.BOOL2 ? YES, so 2013 += 2
> - O1.BOOL3 ? NO
> - O1.BOOL3 ? NO
> - O2.BOOL1 ? NO
> - O2.BOOL2 ? NO
> - O2.BOOL3 ? YES, so 2012 += 6
>
> 2012 : 7 2013 : 2

So I want to display the **number by year**. But the numbers and the years are in different fields.

I have 6 years, numbers and booleans by opportunity.

How can I do?

Comment: Put the table in excel format so that question can be easily readable, Secondly algorithm is not quite clear to understand.

Comment: Thridly, design is not good as every year you will end up creating new 'Year' field